# Textarea realtime update by multiple input values

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my form example:

```
<form action="" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="firstTarget" />
    <input type="text" name="secondTarget" />
    <input type="text" name="thirdTarget" />
    <textarea name="result">I have this text and I want to update it using firstTarget. After that I want to use secondTarget and thirdTarget</textarea>
</form>
```

I want to update my textarea value in realtime by replacing the words firstTarget, secondTarget and thirdTarget with the actual values from firstTarget, secondTarget and thirdTarget inputs.

Comment: No.. I want to update the value of $_POST['result'] relative to my inputs, by replacing the firstTarget keyword from the textarea with the actual value that is filled into firstTarget input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
/* cache original value so we keep the keywords*/
var txt=$('textarea').val();


$('input').keyup(function(){
   var newText=txt;
    newText=newText.replace( this.name, this.value);    
    $('textarea').val(newText);    
});
```

One issue however is if textarea is not set as readonly and user changes anything within it this won't work as it relies on storing the original value and changing that. Would need to know more about use case for this setup to help advance it further.

Same issue exists in other solutions as well if user touches any of the keywords all will fail

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/8nTqu/)**</kbd>

Here's a solution that stores the input value on every keyup so textarea can be edited by user as well.

```
$('input').keyup(function(){
    /* value to be replaced is stored in data object*/
    var regVal=$(this).data('replace');    
   var newText=$('textarea').val().replace( regVal, this.value); 
    /* store value that will get replaced*/  
    $(this).data('replace', this.value)     
    $('textarea').val(newText);    
}).each(function(){
    /* on page load set initial replacement value as name of input*/
    $(this).data('replace', this.name); 
});
```

Only limitation is it assumes no duplicate entries by user

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/8nTqu/)**</kbd>

Comment: @GitaarLAB why do you say only first letter...my demo works with full input value while typing. Agree there are limitiations as I noted. Hard to tell how OP intends to use this

Comment: It was perfect but I found a bug... If I change the value of the textarea and then I write something into an input, the textarea code resets... Is there a way to keep it intact and still update by given inputs?

Comment: @MariutaMihaiDan define `real time` I assumed you want user to see while typing. Also, another issue would be will there possibly be duplicates of what user types and text within textarea?

Comment: Yes.. "real time" is when the user sees what he is writing and a duplicate will never be found...

Comment: We are getting very close to it!

Comment: OK...not perfect because match is created for first letter typed. So if `t` exists and user types `t` will replace wrong one. Could set some length limits if that  helps

Answer (score 1):

HTML:

```
<form action="" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="firstTarget" onblur="tst(this);" />
    <input type="text" name="secondTarget" onblur="tst(this);" />
    <input type="text" name="thirdTarget" onblur="tst(this);" />
    <textarea style="width:500px; height: 100px;" name="result">I have this text and I want to update it using firstTarget. After that I want to use secondTarget and thirdTarget</textarea>
</form>
```

And javascript:

```
function tst(elm){
    var trgt=document.getElementsByTagName('textarea')[0];
    trgt.value=trgt.value.replace(elm.getAttribute('name'), elm.value);
}
```

Working [jsfiddle demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/kJMXa/)

**EDIT:**
should you want to update *multple* instances of your needles like `firstTarget`, then you need to create the regex on the fly so you can pass it the global flag.

```
function tst(elm){
    var trgt=document.getElementsByTagName('textarea')[0];
    trgt.value=trgt.value.replace(RegExp(elm.getAttribute('name'), 'g'), elm.value);
}
```

Working [jsfiddle demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/kJMXa/1/)

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code to do it:

```
$('firstTarget').onChange(function(){
      var str =  $('result').val();
      str.replace(firstTarger, $( this ).attr('name'));
      $('result').text(str);
 }):

 $('secondTarget').onChange(function(){
      var str =  $('result').val();
      str.replace(firstTarger, $( this ).attr('name'));
      $('result').text(str);
 }):

$('thirdTarget').onChange(function(){
      var str =  $('result').val();
      str.replace(firstTarger, $( this ).attr('name'));
      $('result').text(str);
 }):
```

enjoy!!!